# Unexpected list dropout in simple loop

Tags: python, list, for-loop

The following for loop will print each element of the list `ids` as expected:

```
ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for item in ids:
    print(item)

0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

However, when I construct a for-loop that should generate two random numbers, the loop only goes through 5 cycles (on even numbers).  Here, I set **diff** equal to the set of `ids` with the current item number removed.  `diff` should be a set of 9 numbers (so, for the first loop `diff` would be `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`, in the second loop `diff` would be [0,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] etc...  But what happens is that odd numbers of the `ids` list are skipped completely.  Why does this happen when I do not modify the `ids` list at all in the for loop?  How is the `ids` list being modified?

```
ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for item in ids:
    print(item)
    diff = ids
    diff.remove(item)
    test = random.sample(diff, 2)
    print(test)

0
[8, 2]
2
[8, 5]
4
[1, 6]
6
[9, 8]
8
[7, 3]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want

```
diff = ids.copy()
```

What you have means `diff` is just pointing to `ids`, so when you remove elements from `diff`, you're also removing elements from `ids`.

Answer (score 1):

You are modifying `ids` inside the loop, `diff = ids` doesn't create a *new* object, just assigns `diff` to the *same* object. And so you modify `ids` when you modify `diff`. To fix this, do:

```py
diff = ids.copy()
```

Comment: But shouldn't diff be set equal to the ids ?  `ids` is on the right

Comment: Would you elaborate on what you mean? @the_darkside

Comment: My question has been sufficiently answered, I understand now

Comment: Great, glad I could help. This is one thing I don't *love* about Python, when it chooses to create a new object or copy an existing one can seem unintuitive.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of how objects are managed in python's memory. While you might have defined two different variables, you don't actually two different objects. These two names `diff` and `ids` are referring to the same object in Python's memory. Therefore, when you modify one list, you will modify the other one as well, altering the course of for loop each time an iteration happens. I have modified your loop a bit so you can see what I mean:

```
ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(id(ids))
for item in ids:
    print(item)
    diff = ids
    print(id(diff))
    diff.remove(item)
    test = random.sample(diff, 2)
    print(test)
```

I get the following output for the first two iterations:

```
140088760329608 ##This is the id for ids in Python's memory
0
140088760329608 ##This is the id for the diff in Python's memory
```

Therefore, regardless of how we name it, modifying diff or ids, will always modify the object, so when you are calling it (with diff or ids), you will receive the same modified object.

As Collin suggested, you can use `.copy()` to prevent this from happening:

```
ids = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
print(id(ids))
for item in ids:
    print(item)
    diff = ids.copy()
    print(id(diff))
    diff.remove(item)
    test = random.sample(diff, 2)
    print(test)
```

Returns:

```
140088759855944 ##Object id for ids
0
140088759071496 ##Object id for diffs
```

Creating a new object you can safely modify without altering the other one.